# datetime.strptime not working as portrayed widely. Using Python 3.11

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I see several posts talking about datetime.datetime.strptime that can be used to convert date string '12/13/23' to a datetime object. This doesn't work for me.

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('12/13/23', "%m/%d/%y")
```

produces error as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\FirstTest\Scratchpad.py", line 3, in <module>
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('12/24/1964', "%m/%d/%y")
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\_strptime.py", line 352, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 64
```

Many people show the above code with output working as 2023-12-13 as a datetime object. Doesn't work for me

I was expecting `dt.month()` to return the month and `print(dt)` to print `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: voting to close as caused by typo. `"%y"` is for 2-digit years, `"%Y"` for parsing 4-digit years.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't show the same code that you're running as your traceback.

Your code, which works:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('12/13/23', "%m/%d/%y")
```

Your traceback, which doesn't work:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('12/24/1964', "%m/%d/%y")
```

The traceback is correct to produce an error here, the format string you've given is not valid for the date string you've given. `%y` parse 2-digit year, and `1964` is not a 2-digit year, you need `%Y` if you want to parse a 4-digit year.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer helped. It works. However when you give 2 digit year with %y and you try to print the year with date.year, it prints prefix of 20xx (e.g. 2064 in my example above). If I wanted it to print 19xx what should I do?